# How to mitigate query performance impact of replication in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have about 4M doc index in SOLR (4.1). One master rebuilds an index (it doesn't get any real traffic) once a day and replication is done to two slaves. During the replication, I found that some queries timeout. I am wondering if there is a way to mitigate that?

Comment: This is a complex issue.  Is the timeout reflected in long running queries in your tomcat log (or other servlet container log)? It could be network lag when your replication starves out the interface... or starves out the disk.  You have to look and gather metrics to determine what the server was doing when the timeouts occured.  New relic is a great product for helping with that.

Comment: A very good point. It looks like it is network bandwidth saturation. Is there a way to throttle in some fashion?

Comment: you could spread your changes out over time and replicate more often so the changes are smaller?

Comment: another thing you could do it put a second nic in the master and have it replicate to the other servers on that nic and limit it to a slower speed... but in that case why not just add more nics and put the communication between solr servers on their own switch.